# How to work on count in ms sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Below is my query. I can't understand how count statement works in the below mentioned query.

```
SQL > SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS 
GROUP BY age 
HAVING COUNT(age) >= 2;
```

how does count statement work in this?

Comment: You are grouping by `age` and yet you want to display `*`. Just type out the columns you want to have displayed and add them to the `GROUP BY` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query can't be executed because of `*` in select.

Basically, if you have `group by` in your query - then you can select either columns in `group by` statement or results of applying some aggregate functions to columns (for example, `sum`, `max`, `min` and so on).

Concerning your question - for example, if you change it to

```
SELECT COUNT(age), age FROM CUSTOMERS 
GROUP BY age 
HAVING COUNT(age) >= 2;
```

you will get recordset describing "how many customers has appropriate age", assuming that count >=2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT age,count(*) FROM CUSTOMERS 
GROUP BY age 
HAVING COUNT(age) >= 2;
```